# adding array into csv file - two array values on the same row different column

Tags: php

I have a php page that is creating a csv file for download which is made up of an array. 
Short version of Array:

```
$data = array("Joe Bloggs", "jbloggs", "John Doe", "jdoe")
```

My array is made from output from other commands so i cant just change the layout of my array, i can make two arrays, one for names and one for usernames if that help achieve my goal.

This is what i am doing to add the array values into my csv file:

```
$output = fopen('php://output', 'wb');
fputcsv($output, array('Name', 'Username'));
foreach ($data as $line ) {
    $val = explode(",", $line);
    for ($i=0; $i<$val["count"]; $i++); {

    fputcsv($output , array($val[$i])); 
    }
}

fclose($output);
```

This gives me a csv that looks like this:

```
Name      | Username
Joe Bloggs|
jbloggs   |
John Does |
jdoe      |
```

Really i need to have the usernames on the same row but in the username column. 
I have tried this and lots of variations on this but it does not seem to work, my thinking was i increase N by two each time so $i will be the name because it is every other index position and then when doing the fputcsv it would add 1 to $i so it would grab the username as it is the value after the name.

```
foreach ($data as $line ) {
    $val = explode(",", $line);
    for ($i=0; $i<$val["count"]; $i+=2); {

    fputcsv($output , array($val[$i], $val[$i+1])); 
    }
}

fclose($output);
```

Using the above gives me all the values in column one still.

Apologies for the write my code style question but i am out of my depth on this and cant find how to get to two consecutive values in a for loop of an array.

Comment: `$val[i+1]` - you meant `$i` there, not `i`.

Comment: I did thanks got rid of the error but still get all values in one collumn

Comment: Well how much “exploding by comma” do you expect to actually happen on a value like `Joe Bloggs`? That value looks pretty comma-less to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is 1 way of doing it.

```
$output = fopen('php://output', 'wb');
fputcsv($output, array('Name', 'Username'));

$temp = []; //Define a temp array.
foreach ($data as $line ) {
    $temp[]= $line;
    if( count( $temp) == 2 ) { //If no. of values in temp array is 2, write to csv file
        fputcsv($output , $temp );
        $temp = []; //initialize $temp;
    }
}

fclose($output);
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can use simply these two line codes.**

```
  for ($i=0 ;$i < count($data);$i+2) {       
     fputcsv($output , $data[$i],$data[$i+1]);          
  }
```